# NullPointerException al llamar a un service

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hola estoy configurando una aplicación web con Spring y al llamar a un service desde el Bean me sale error de null pointer exception. Ese servicio esta a null. No entiendo porqué es, ¿alguna ayuda?
Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "alumnoBean")
@SessionScoped
public class AlumnoBean {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger
           .getLogger(AlumnoBean.class);

    public AlumnoBean() {
        System.out.println("AlumnosBean()");
    }

    @Autowired
    private AlumnoBL serviceAlumnoBL;

    public List<Alumno> getAlumnosList(){
            return serviceAlumnoBL.findAllBL();
    }

}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AlumnoBLImpl implements AlumnoBL {

    @Autowired
    private AlumnoDao dao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Alumno> findAllBL() {
        return dao.findAllDAO();
    }
```

DAO:

```
@Repository
public class AlumnoDaoImpl implements AlumnoDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<Alumno> findAllDAO() {
        return (List<Alumno>) 
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Alumno").list();
    }
```

LLAMADA:

```
<ui:repeat var="list" value="#{alumnoBean.alumnosList}">
    <h:inputText value="#{list.id}"> 
<ui:repeat>
```

spring-servlet.xml (com.auto es el paquete donde se encuentran beans, BL Daos y models):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.auto" />
```

ERROR: el error no me sale al lanzar el servidor si no al meterme en la página, es decir cuando llama al serviceAlumnoBL.findAll(); ya que serviceAlumnoBL es null:

```
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @17,58 value="#{alumnoBean.alumnosList}": Error reading 'alumnosList' en el tipo com.auto.bean.AlumnoBean
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getValue(UIRepeat.java:279)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:523)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:577)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1110)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'alumnosList' en el tipo com.auto.bean.AlumnoBean
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
... 34 more
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error 
    at com.auto.bean.AlumnoBean.getAlumnosList(AlumnoBean.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)
... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.auto.bean.AlumnoBean.getAlumnosList(AlumnoBean.java:31)
... 44 more

nov 20, 2017 8:28:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [Faces Servlet] en el contexto con ruta [/Autoescuela] lanzó la excepción [null] con causa raíz
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.auto.bean.AlumnoBean.getAlumnosList(AlumnoBean.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getValue(UIRepeat.java:279)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:523)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:577)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1110)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el trozo de código donde obtienes y usas la clase AlumnoBean?

Comment: Buenas, si Spring no encuentra un bean, debería darte un error a la hora de arrancar el proyecto. ¿Cuándo te ocurre este NPE?, ¿podrías pasar la traza de error que te da?
también estaría bien si pudieras pasar la interfaz AlumnoBL.

Si el error no te da en el arranque, es posible que estés creando el bean AlumnoBean a mano con un AlumnoBean = new AlumnoBean(); con lo que Spring no inyecta las dependencias adecuadas (tendrías que hacerlo a mano). Para darte una respuesta lo mejor es que digas cómo y cuándo te da el error exactamente.

Comment: El error me salta cuando desde la vista llamo al bean "AlumnoBean" que si que lo encuentra, incluso llama al método. Pero el serviceAlumnoBL del Bean se encuentra a null y por eso no accede a su método findAll();

Comment: Tu código cuesta de seguir por varios motivos, yo te recomendaría hacer lo siguiente. Elimina las llamadas a métodos dentro de los atributos de tu clase, esto es una mala práctica porque vas a estar entrando a ese método cada vez que instancies la clase (además de que en el futuro puede que reutilices esa clase y no quieras cargar esa lista). Quita también el try/catch de la lista que no tiene sentido, si la búsqueda no encuentra nada, tu lista debería estar vacía y ya está.
Lo adecuado sería que cargues la vista en el momento en el que accedas a la vista que la necesita.

Comment: Has puesto dos clases con el mismo nombre, corrige esa parte porque hace difícil seguir el flujo.

Comment: Primero debes de confirmar que has configurado el faces-config.xml y el web.xml para utilizar la inyección de dependencias con Spring, segundo si no tienes experiencia no te recomiendo mezclar estas 2 tecnologías porque jsf y spring implementan su propio sistema de inyección. JSF puede utilizar la inyección Spring (pero no al contrario) hay anotaciones que no funcionaran de jsf o anotaciones que funcionan pero no como lo harían normalmente porque solo puede existir un sistema de inyección o spring o jsf y Spring para tener retro compatibilidad no implemento todo el estándar CDI.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que inicializar el servicio con el contexto de Spring. Cuando pones el @Autowired para inicializarlo, no sirve porque no se entera de que tiene que inicializarlo y es nulo.

Para inicializarlo con Spring, seria algo parecido a esto:

```
protected AlumnoBL serviceAlumnoBL = 
        new SpringContextManualLoad<AlumnoBL>().initializeBean(AlumnoBL.class);
```

Comment: Si el código del usuario estuviera correctamente, los bean deberían ser levantados con Sprign automáticamente, la solución sería encontrar el problema que está impidiendo que esto ocurra no forzar a que el bean se inicie a mano.